# dynamodb table tables design for multi user sharing applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Sorry for the abstract title of the question but i will try to explain my intention in details in my question.

I want to create a reminders application in which each user has a separate login in the system but he/she can choose to share an item(in this case a reminder) with another user if he/she chooses. So when that user with whom the item is shared searches in his app he can also see the reminders which are shared with him.

So a user can have a reminder for only himself + a reminder which is shared with him.

This are my data access/retrieval patterns:

1. So when a user goes inside the application he should be able to see a list of reminders that he created and also the ones which are shared with him
2. From that list he should be able to search for a reminder by tag(i plan to do that outside dynamodb since the tag would be a set and not a scalar field hence i cannot have an index on that) and also should be able to search for a reminder by title
   3.A user should be able to update or delete a reminder
   4.A user should be able to create a reminder
   5.Also the user should only be able to see future reminders and not the ones in which the expiration date is passed

The table and index creation that i have is created using the below `create_table` script :

```
import boto3


def create_reminders_table():
    """Just create the reminders table."""
    session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dynamo_local')
    dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")
    table = dynamodb.create_table(
        TableName='Reminders',
        KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'reminder_id',
                'KeyType': 'HASH'
            }
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'reminder_id',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'user_id',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'reminder_title_reminder_id',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            }
        ],
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes=[
            {
                'IndexName': 'UserTitleReminderIdGsi',
                'KeySchema': [
                    {
                        'AttributeName': 'user_id',
                        'KeyType': 'HASH'
                    },
                    {
                        'AttributeName': 'reminder_title_reminder_id',
                        'KeyType': 'RANGE'
                    }
                ],
                'Projection': {
                    'ProjectionType': 'INCLUDE',
                    'NonKeyAttributes': [
                        'reminder_expiration_date_time'
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        BillingMode='PAY_PER_REQUEST'
    )
    return table


if __name__ == '__main__':
    movie_table = create_reminders_table()
    print("Table status:", movie_table.table_status)
```

So the decision for the global secondary index us to allow a user to search for reminders with a reminder title.

Now to achieve the above case in which a user wants to also share his reminder with someone else i want to do the below change to my table schema . Basically i want to rename the `user_id` attribute to something like `users_id` which initially contains the user id of the user who created it but if that reminder is shared with someone then the user_id of the second user is also concatenated with the creator user id and the `users_id` column is modified .

If i do this i have 2 issues which i can think of:

1. How do i know the `user_id` of the user with whom the reminder is shared ? May be now i need to maintain a new table holding user information ? Or can i use some other service like amazon cognito for this?
2. If i still have the Global Secondary index on the `users_id` column when i need to search for reminders for a user the query needs to be like : `select * from reminders where users_id startswith("Bob")`( for example) .
3. Another option which i can think of(preferred way) is to drop the idea of creating a `users_id` attribute but instead of keeping the `user_id` column as is . I would the add the `user_id` as a sort key (RANGE) key to the table so that the combination of `reminder_id` and `user_id` is unique. Then when a user wants to share his created reminder with some other user a new entry is created inside the database with the same `reminder_id` and a new user id (which is the user id of the user with whom the reminder is shared)

Any help on my dilemma would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention your query access pattern in any detail, and with DynamoDB your data model flows from the query access pattern. So the below is based only on my imagination of what query patterns you might need. I could be off.

The PK can be the `user_id`. The SK can be the `reminder_id` of all reminders the user keeps. That lets you do a `Query` to get all reminders for a given user. The primary key then is the user id and reminder id in combination, so if you're passing around a reference, use that (not just the `reminder_id`).

A share gets added by putting another item under the `user_id` of the person getting shared with. That way a Query for that user can retrieve both their own reminders and those shared with them.

If you need people to list what reminders they've shared and with others, you can put that into the reminder itself as a list of who it's been shared with, if the list is short enough, or instead create a GSI on that share reference (against a `shared_by` attribute) if the list might be large.

If you need to query for a user's reminders and differentiate their own vs shared, you can prepend the SK with that so `SHARED#reminder_id` or `SELF#reminder_id` so a `begins_with` on the SK can differentiate.

You can refine this in various ways, but I think it would optimize for the "show me my reminders and the reminders shared with me" use cases, while making sharing (or undoing sharing) easy to implement.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer i have updated the question with my data access patterns . After you have a look at it may i can ask further questions :)

Comment: OK, so the same basic model would apply. For tag and text search you'll integrate with a system like OpenSearch. To handle future reminders you can filter based on timestamp or to be more efficient put it into the SK for index-optimized retrieval like SHARED#2022-02-15#reminder_id so you can use SK ranges to find all SHARED or SELF reminders beyond today's date/time.